# Can Maven compile POM dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

If a `pom.xml` contains a list of project dependencies like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Does maven support some command line argument to recompile `my-project`?

Note: `my-project` is found in the `CLASSPATH` and could be specified using some `XML` element.

Comment: Did you mean something like this ? [How_do_I_build_more_than_one_project_at_once](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_build_more_than_one_project_at_once)

Answer (score 5):

No. Compile scope simply means that your dependency must be available at compile time of your app/library.

Answer (score 1):

Like Michael-O said, you the `compile` scope defines the point in time when you need this dependency (in this case during compilation).

The answer is no, but it is also doable.

Make all your modules produce a `sources` artifact. Then use the `maven-dependency-plugin` to extract them from the dependency tree into some directory. Using an invocation of the `antrun-maven-plugin` you can instruct Maven to compile these dependencies.

I frankly don't understand *why* you would want to do this, as your CI (continuous integration) server should already be deploying the binary + source artifacts to your artifact repository server.

Either way, I hope this helps.